# how to return the result in my form just using php?

Tags: php, forms

In this case, I don't want to use javascript, jquery or similars (If is not possible, show how to do it using jquery). I want to use just php to make this task. It's an example that is simple but I can't resolve it.

I have one php form

form.php

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="test.php">
    <button name="create" id="create">create</button>
    <button name="edit" id="edit">Edit</button>
    <button name="remove" id="remove">Remove</button>

        <div class='message'>

        </div>
</form>
```

A class

Event.php

```
class Event{
    protected $name;

    public function setName($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }   
}
```

and the file that will process the post data

test.php

```
<?php
require 'Event.php';

$evento = new Event();

if(isset($_POST)){  
        if(isset($_POST['create'])){
            $result = "created!";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
            $result = "edited!";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
            $result = "deleted!";
        }

        $event->setName($result);
        return $event->getName();

    } 
?>
```

I want to put the content of the variable `$result` inside the div with class `message` according the button submitted. Only that. How can I do it?

Comment: Where is the variable `$content` ?

Comment: sorry, is the variable $result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U need `session` for this purpose.

Try this code (test.php) :

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'Event.php';

$evento = new Event();

if(isset($_POST)){  
        if(isset($_POST['create'])){
            $result = "created!";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
            $result = "edited!";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
            $result = "deleted!";
        }

        $event->setName($result);
        $_SESSION["data"] = $event->getName();
        header("Location : form.php");

    } 
?>
```

form.php

```
<div class='message'>
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["data"]) && $_SESSION["data"] != "") {
    echo $_SESSION["data"];
    unset($_SESSION["data"]);
}
?>
</div>
```

**Without Session**

If you want to do this without session then you need to combine two file `test.php` and `form.php` into single file. So in this scenario you need this code :

```
<?php
require 'Event.php';

$evento = new Event();

$result = "";
if(isset($_POST)){  
        if(isset($_POST['create'])){
            $result = "created!";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
            $result = "edited!";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
            $result = "deleted!";
        }

        $event->setName($result);


    } 
?>
<form name="form" method="post">
    <button name="create" id="create">create</button>
    <button name="edit" id="edit">Edit</button>
    <button name="remove" id="remove">Remove</button>

        <div class='message'>
        <?php if($result != "") { echo $result; }?>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `test.php` also needs to redirect back to `form.php` when it's done.

Comment: Yes. Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Then I must to use sessions in this case?

Comment: @DiegodeSouzaSilva There is other way also. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: I don't know who did it

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> return $event->getName();
> ```

`return` is meaningless outside of a function.

If you want to put something in the HTTP response then you need to `print` it (or `echo` it, or put it outside of `<?php ... ?>`, etc).

Comment: I understood, but how can I put the content inside the div?

Comment: `<div><?php print $event->getName(); ?></div>`

Answer (score 0):

you can use echo ,var_dump or print_r to get the value.
some frameworks have offer you functions to print the value such as ThinkPHP

Comment: But I want to know how can I put the content of the variable inside the div above